# How to receive mongodb code to perform direct database changes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to develop an endpoint that will receive MongoDB commands and run them directly on the database like robomongo does and return the results. It can be anything(insert, update, read, delete, etc). I am using mongoose so the way to do it can be via mongoose or pure mongo code.

I thought about using something like:

```
let code = eval(stringOfMongoCode);
db.eval(code);
```

But I thought to myself that it has to be a better way, because [db.eval()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) is deprecated since version 3.0 and I am currently using version 3.6 of mongo.

Any ideas on how to do that?

**Edit 1:** This is what I did so far. It works and I was able to run anything in the database and respond with the results(I removed some code):

```
app.post('/v1/query', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let code = `(function() { ${req.body.code} })`;
        code = eval(code);
        const mongoose = require("mongoose");
        const db = mongoose.connection.db;
        let result = await db.eval(code);
        res.status(200);
        return res.json(BaseController.buildResponse(true, 'Database code executed', null, result));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500);
        return res.json(BaseController.buildResponse(false, 'Error running your code on the database', err));
    }
});
```

I still would like to improve my code not using `db.eval()` and being able to return the results of anything.

Comment: What you are describing is effectively a [REST API](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/). There are some generic solutions (open source and otherwise) or you could build a custom API for your requirements. You definitely don't want to be using `db.eval()` as this comes with serious security and performance limitations (and will be removed in a future release of MongoDB). However, recommending a specific REST interface or library would be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Stennie I already have a REST API with ExpressJS running. What I want to build is one generic endpoint on this API that will be able to run anything directly on the MongoDB. I do know about the security regarding this feature but I already have a strong authentication verification regarding this endpoint and it will only be accessed by technical admins. If you think about it, what I need is a web interface to manage the database.